# Can someone identify this font?

Tags: font-identification, serif

Can someone tell me what font was used for the text in the scroll banner at the bottom of the image?

[image: Crest]

Thanks!

Comment: I tried a number of automatic services, including IdentiFont, WhatFontIs, Font.org, and BowfinWorks.  Font.org seemed to be the most successful, suggesting Caxton Light.  While this font is similar, it definitely does not match several letters.  Hence, expert help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be [Bernard Modern Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/bernhard-modern/bold/) font:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used Identifont.com and it said that the font is Cartier

Source:

http://www.identifont.com/show?41F

Get the font from http://www.identifont.com/link?BH1M36+2HRC and search for that font and install it.

Comment: Nice try, but the `Q` is nothing like the example image